# Change font of custome key (label) of android custom keyboard

Tags: java, android, unicode, fonts, keyboard

I am having a problem with changing the font style (non English - Unicode) of the custom keys of android custom keyboard.
I have followed something similar to the answer of this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34332318/can-i-change-the-output-font-of-an-android-custom-keyboard)
and it seems working fine for single character buttons. It will change the font of entire app to the new font including single character keys of the keyboard.
If I wanna change the size of the key text I can use below two entries

```
android:keyTextSize="25sp" // for single character keys
android:labelTextSize="20sp" // for multiple character keys
```

But unfortunately method in above link only works for single character keys only. Is there any way to set the font of multiple character keys.

See below image for example:
First button has some default system font while second and third buttons have the correct font.

[image]

**EDIT**:
After reading *Bhavita Lalwani* [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37560032/5685196) it got me thinking.

```
if (label != null) {
        // For characters, use large font. For labels like "Done", use small font.
        if (label.length() > 1 && key.codes.length < 2) {
            paint.setTextSize(mLabelTextSize);
            paint.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
        } else {
            paint.setTextSize(mKeyTextSize);
            paint.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT);
                }
            }
```

here it says

```
if (label.length() > 1 && key.codes.length < 2)
```

so it uses BOLD fonts for multiple characters only if they have single code.
eg. I think Android Engs thinking about these things. ???

```
Keyboard.KEYCODE_DONE
Keyboard.KEYCODE_DELETE
```

So the ugly workaround will be to add multiple codes and only use first code when needed.

```
<Key android:codes="5001,1" android:keyLabel="AB" android:keyWidth="12%p" />
```

Now every key with multiple codes also user DEFAULT typeface.
This works for now, (Until I find a proper solution :))

Answer (score 2):

I was having a similar issue in creating Hindi custom keyboard.(Non English-Unicode)

So let's find your culprit why this variation happens.

[KeyboardView.java in Android Source code](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/inputmethodservice/KeyboardView.java)

lines 701-709

```
            if (label != null) {
            // For characters, use large font. For labels like "Done", use small font.
            if (label.length() > 1 && key.codes.length < 2) {
                paint.setTextSize(mLabelTextSize);
                paint.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
            } else {
                paint.setTextSize(mKeyTextSize);
                paint.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT);
                    }
                }
```

This means it makes multi character labels to Bold and different size.
And single char labels stay as it is.

**Solution**

Create a CustomKeyboardView class which extends this KeyboardView class

```
public class CustomKeyboardView extends KeyboardView {

public CustomKeyboardView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}
```

Now in this CustomKeyboardView class, override onDraw method. This method would be called when drawing the keyboard and keys on the canvas

```
@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    Paint mpaint = new Paint();
    mpaint.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD); //to make all Bold. Choose Default to make all normal font
    mpaint.setTextSize(24); // in px


    List<Key> keys = getKeyboard().getKeys();
    for (Keyboard.Key key : keys) {

        if (key.label != null) {
            String keyLabel = key.label.toString();
            canvas.drawText(keyLabel, key.x + key.width, key.y + key.height, mpaint);
        } else if (key.icon != null) {
            key.icon.setBounds(key.x, key.y, key.x + key.width, key.y + key.height);
            key.icon.draw(canvas);
        }
    }
}
```

You can use this cheatcode to use sp for setTextSize method

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <dimen name="custom_text_size">25sp</dimen>
</resources>
```

and

```
mpaint.setTextSize(getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.custom_text_size));
```

Finally just as we used to create the Keyboard,

```
     KeyboardView kv = (CustomKeyboardView) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.mainkeyboard, null); //mainkeyboard
     Keyboard  keyboard = new Keyboard(this, R.xml.hindi); //Your Keyboard Layout
     kv.setKeyboard(keyboard); //Set the keyboard
```

And you are good to go.

Hope it helps :D

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't really worked for me. Custom key still displays wrong font. But this gave me an idea. See my edited question second part.

Comment: Are you sure,its not working?It worked for me.
However I had to remove super.onDraw. (from the code I wrote above),
Because it obviously was using the set of codes, and drawing it using bold,default before I can draw them seperately.

Try removing super.onDraw from the overridden onDraw(Do checkout additional dependencies you may need from the actual implemetation of onDraw.)

P.S its my first answer. So apologies, if it din work for you.

Comment: if i use this anothere text is creating with this font on the same kay