# How To Apply Font in Custom Android Keyboard

Tags: android, typeface

I want to implement custom `keyboard` for android and I want to apply font on `keyboard`.

I am using Typeface in `KeyboardView` class but this is not work for me.

```
 @Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);
    int scaledSize = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(
            R.dimen.alternate_key_label_size);
    Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/Nastaleeq.ttf");
    paint.setTypeface(tf);
    paint.setTextSize(scaledSize);
    paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
}
```

Comment: One option is that, create your own custom text view for keyboard and its input field.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I change the output font of an Android custom keyboard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34332318/can-i-change-the-output-font-of-an-android-custom-keyboard)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**One solution** is to use keboardView.java instead of android.inputmethodservice.KeyboardView.

You also need to change paint.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD) to paint.setTypeface(my font) and you must add attrs.xml to your project.

**Another solution:**

changing the font style inside the application.
create a simple class named **FontOverride**.

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Typeface;

public final class FontsOverride {

public static void setDefaultFont(Context context,
        String staticTypefaceFieldName, String fontAssetName) {
    final Typeface regular = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),
            fontAssetName);
    replaceFont(staticTypefaceFieldName, regular);
}

protected static void replaceFont(String staticTypefaceFieldName,
        final Typeface newTypeface) {
    try {
        final Field staticField = Typeface.class
                .getDeclaredField(staticTypefaceFieldName);
        staticField.setAccessible(true);
        staticField.set(null, newTypeface);
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
}
```

add this class to your code.

```
public final class Application extends android.app.Application {
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    FontsOverride.setDefaultFont(this, "DEFAULT", "fonts/Nastaleeq.ttf");
    FontsOverride.setDefaultFont(this, "MONOSPACE", "fonts/GeezEdit.ttf");

  }
}
```

here you can see that some fonts/fontname are added. These are the external font files which you can use to override into your keyboard view/labels.

add this Application name into the android manifest file application name

example:

```
<application
    android:name=".Application"
    android:allowBackup="false"
    android:installLocation="internalOnly"
    android:label="@string/ime_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
```

now update the above-override font name into your style. base theme or the theme which you are using at your manifest application.

example:

```
 <!-- Application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <item name="android:typeface">monospace</item>
</style>
```

This will work to change the user provided the font to the android project or application.

Answer (score 1):

## Try This

- you've to add these lines in `onDraw`

---

```
Paint mPaint = new Paint();
        mPaint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);
        mPaint.setTextSize(40);
        mPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);

        Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(mContext.getAssets(),"normal_font.ttf");
        mPaint.setTypeface(font);

        if (key.label != null) {
            String keyLabel = key.label.toString();
            if (caps) {
                keyLabel = keyLabel.toUpperCase();
            }
            canvas.drawText(keyLabel, key.x + (key.width / 2),
                    key.y + (key.height / 2) , mPaint);
        } else if (key.icon != null) {
            key.icon.setBounds(key.x, key.y, key.x + key.width, key.y + key.height);
            key.icon.draw(canvas);
        }
}
```