# Keylabel of Softkeyboard to change text size and font of keytext

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, android-fonts

I want to customize softkeyboard. I want to change the text size and font of keytext of keylabel. I have tried many methods but no change in keypad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement a [KeyboardView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/inputmethodservice/KeyboardView), then you can customize almost everything in the keyboard's design.

To change de text size you can set the attribute [android:keyTextSize](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/inputmethodservice/KeyboardView.html#attr_android:keyTextSize).

Unfortunately the isn't a way to change the font style in the xml, you will need to do it programmatically extending a class from KeyboardView. In this case I would suggest [Phillip's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31303285/5791681):

```
public class MyKeyboardView extends KeyboardView {
@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);
    Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),
        "fonts/Hippie.otf"); //Insert your font here.
    paint.setTypeface(font);

    List<Key> keys = getKeyboard().getKeys();
    for(Key key: keys) {
        if(key.label != null)
            canvas.drawText(key.label.toString(), key.x, key.y, paint);
        }
    }
}
```

Another way would be changing your app's font, like [Ankush Bist said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34355265/5791681):

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field; 
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Typeface;

public final class FontsOverride {

public static void setDefaultFont(Context context,
        String staticTypefaceFieldName, String fontAssetName) {
    final Typeface regular = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),
            fontAssetName);
    replaceFont(staticTypefaceFieldName, regular);
}

protected static void replaceFont(String staticTypefaceFieldName,
        final Typeface newTypeface) {
    try {
           final Field staticField = Typeface.class
                .getDeclaredField(staticTypefaceFieldName);
           staticField.setAccessible(true);
           staticField.set(null, newTypeface);
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

Here you can see another similar question: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46577787/how-to-apply-font-in-custom-android-keyboard)

And at last you can fully customize a xml layout like what I did [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34799775/soft-keyboards-popup-layout/35873098#35873098)